# Why are my calculations 17px off on height?

Tags: html, css

I want to set the content height manually so that my app fills the screen.  This is the code that does this:

```
let headerHeight = $("#navBar").height();
let footerHeight = $("#footer").height();
let browserWindowHeight = $(window).height();
let contentHeight = browserWindowHeight - (headerHeight + footerHeight);
$("#pageHost").height(contentHeight);
```

However, it is too large by 17 pixels, but I can't find where they are coming from.

I have carefully looked through the chrome developer tools, and all calculations appear correct.  I have set

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

to ensure that border-box is being used.

But I keep getting a scrollbar unless I subtract 17 from the total.

How do I resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's the combined margin/padding I don't remember
try in html/body selector

```
html,body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

HTML tags like `body` and `html` come with a default margin (8px if I'm not mistaken on the number). I'm not sure about if they also have any padding. Please, if this was the answer you were looking for, expand on exact numbers.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I found a margin in the content of the footer. It is working as expected now.

Comment: Glad i could help. @GregGum please accept answer if post is resolved

Comment: You can drop the `padding: 0`